# IF ELSE STATEMENT IN Classic email template

Tags: apex, code-coverage

Can I add a condition to add number of terms (number field) to the installment date (date field) in Classic Email Template. Example: Number of terms is 30 and Installment Date is 3/01/2023 in the email Template Payment Due By: 4/01/2023 (installment date
plus terms).

If terms is 0 populate the next installment date, please help.

I'm looking for a way to this in the classic email template without create a custom formula field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No.

Classic templates don't support "expressions," which is what you'd need to calculate a value directly in the template. Use a Visualforce template, or you'll have to create a formula field.